# Use editable div height change to add and remove classes to other DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I have and editable div that allow users to enter text. This is part of a chat widget so the design needs the box to be fixed to the bottom.

When a user types I need javascript to catch the resize and append classes to elements where needed.

I managed to get the box to resize upwards but I have had a lot of trouble scaling it back down again.

I have been stuck on this for days now, so any help now would be greatly appreciated.

I have the function and a basic UI version here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/et7wzr1q/1/)

Its probably really simple but I am having no luck figuring this out

> [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/et7wzr1q/1/)

```
var chatBoxSize = {
    oldHeight : 0,
    scrollHeight : 0,
    lastClass : 1,
    minClass : 1,
    maxClass : 5,
    min_height : 0,
    last_size : 0,
    getClass : function (size){
        var sizes = [chatBoxSize.min_height, chatBoxSize.min_height * 2, chatBoxSize.min_height * 3, chatBoxSize.min_height * 4, chatBoxSize.min_height * 5];
        switch (size){ case sizes[0] : return 1; break; case sizes[1] : return 2; break; case sizes[2] : return 3; break; case sizes[3] : return 4; break; case sizes[4] : return 5; break; };
        //is not exact
        var r = null;
        console.log(size);
        for(var x = 0; x < sizes.length; x++){
            if(x < sizes.length){
                if(size >= sizes[x] && size < sizes[(x + 1)]){
                    return (x + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return chatBoxSize.maxClass;
    }
};
$(function () {
    chatBoxSize.min_height = parseInt($('#msgWriteArea').height());
    chatBoxSize.max_height = chatBoxSize.min_height * 4;
    chatBoxSize.last_size = chatBoxSize.min_height;
});
function updateChatSize() {
    var id = '#msgWriteArea';
    var element = document.querySelector(id);
    var size = $(id)[0].scrollHeight;
    var container = $('.container');
    var toRemove = 'size_' + chatBoxSize.lastClass;
    console.log(chatBoxSize.getClass(size));
        chatBoxSize.lastClass = chatBoxSize.getClass(size);
        console.log('Add new class', chatBoxSize.lastClass);
        chatBoxSize.last_size = size;
        $(id).removeClass(toRemove);
        $(id).addClass('size_' + chatBoxSize.lastClass);
        container.removeClass(toRemove);
        container.addClass('size_' + chatBoxSize.lastClass);
        $('#display').val('Removed ' + toRemove + ' Added ' + chatBoxSize.lastClass);
};
$(function (){
    $('#msgWriteArea').bind('change keydown input', function () {
        if(event.type == 'keydown'){
            updateChatSize();
        }
    });
})
```

I have thought of just setting the heights to auto but that will not work with the rest of the ui elements.

Comment: (Offtopic) what kind of chat is that which changes colors depending on editable height?... I'm positive that (knowing the full design) it would be trivial for the other UI elements to adjust....

Comment: You're overcomplicating the whole code, starting from `$('#msgWriteArea').bind('change keydown input', function() {` -> it can be done simply as `$('#msgWriteArea').on('input', updateChatSize);`

Comment: It doesn't change colour I used that in the fiddle to show the class changes, and using on instead of bind its is cleaner but still doesnt decrease in size

Comment: Also the question is... do you need to change classes depending on the number of lines or depending on the exact element height (cause the height thing makes not much sense as it stands :\ )

Comment: Lines might work better, I didnt know you measure the lines thats why I used height

Comment: Exactly, cause if your requirement is to get the number of lines that it's all trivially simpler and doable (with a proper CSS) in a couple od JS lines.

Comment: Looking at your CSS, if your requirement is to add an overflow-y scroll than.. c'mon all you need is CSS and `max-height` and overflow-y set as default to `auto;`

Comment: This is the way I have told to build it, as the user types the box gets bigger and the objects move or resize depending on the size of the box. In the full UI the messages themselves would move upwards. I can add more to the Fiddle if it would help. As long as i can add the corrct class depending on size i can work the rest out from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say but **No JS needed at all**
`flex` to the rescue, `overflow-y: auto;` and `max-height` to the editable DIV:

Heres a ***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/meyeco/1/edit?html,css,output)*** so you can play and resize the browser

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;font:16px/1 sans-serif; color:#444;}


#chat{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100%;
}
#messages{
  flex:1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#messages > div{
  padding: 24px;
  background: #eef;
  margin: 4px 0;
}
#ui{
  background: #eee;
}
#msgWriteArea{
  padding: 24px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:100%;
  background:#ddd;
  max-height:100px;    /* if max height is exceeded */
  overflow-y: auto;    /* add scrollbars */
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
  <div id="messages">
    <div>Message 1</div>
    <div>Message 2</div>
    <div>Message 3</div>
    <div>Message 4</div>
    <div>Message 5</div>
    <div>Message 6</div>      
  </div>
  <div id="ui">
    <div id="msgWriteArea" contenteditable>Some text message</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, if you still really need to the the message area height (for some reasons) you could count the **number of lines** using JS.

Comment: That's definitely an easier way, how's flex with ie

Comment: @PaulLedger you can always use `display:table` and `table-cell` for the first child elements containers if you have problems with `flex` support